# What is difference between new and new[1]?

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation, new-operator

What is difference between `new` and `new[1]`? Can I use `delete` with `new[1]`?

*Edit*

Well well well, I should've provided the background, sorry for that. I was evaluating BoundsChecker at work with VS 2010 and it complained about a memory leak when I used delete[] on new[1]. So in theory I know how the new and delete pair should be used but this particular situation confused me about the things under the hood. Any idea whats happening?

Answer (score 14):

Ed and aix are right, but there is much more going on underneath the hood.

If you use new, then delete, the delete call will execute one destructor.

If you use new[], you must use delete[], but how can delete[] know how much destructors to call?  There might be an array of 2 instances, or one of 2000 instances?
What some (possibly most or all) compilers do, is to store the number of instances right before the memory it returns to you.

So if you call new[5], then new will allocate memory like this:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 5 | instance1 | instance2 | instance3 | instance4 | instance5 |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

And you get a pointer back to instance1.

If you later call delete[], delete[] will use the number (in this case 5) to see how many destructors it needs to call before freeing the memory.

Notice that if you mix new with delete[], or new[] with delete, it can go horribly wrong, because the number might be missing, or the number might be incorrect.

If mixing new[1] with delete works, you might be just lucky, but don't rely on it.

Answer (score 10):

`new` creates an instance, whereas `new[1]` creates a single-element array. `new[1]` will almost certainly incur (small) memory overhead compared to `new` to store the size of the array. You can't use non-default constructors with `new[]`.

`new` must be used with `delete`.

`new[]` must be used with `delete[]`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you must have a default constructor when using new[].  This is often overlooked.

Comment: On the other hand, on most systems, there will be no difference in the memory overhead for types with trivial destructors (but a difference is allowed).

Comment: @NPE ***You can't use non-default constructors with new[]***.Could you please explaint that more in details? Do you mean if a specific class has no valid default constructor, then it could not be used with `new []`? Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

new[] is an operator to allocate and initialize an array of objects and return a pointer to the first element. This differs from the new operator which has the same behavior but for one allocation, not an array.  For deallocation and object destruction, new should be used with delete and new[] with delete[].

```
// operator new[] and new example

// create array of 5 integers
int * p1 = new int[5];
delete[] p1;

// regular allocation of one int
int * p1 = new int;
delete p1;
```

(see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new%5b%5d/) for more details)

Answer (score 0):

'new[1]' creates an array of one item. Need to use `delete[]` to free the memory. `new` just creates an object. Use `delete` with it.